# How to hookup input boxes to Reactjs / Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I not 100% sure if I am doing this right as per the redux design.

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import 'materialize-css/sass/materialize.scss';
import NavigationContainer from './NavigationContainer';

import AddStorageModal from './AddStorageModal.js'
import {loadAddStorageModal, createNewStorage} from '../actions/StorageActions.js'
import '../styles/main.scss';


class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <NavigationContainer />
        <AddStorageModal {...this.props} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        storages: state.storages
    };
}

function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return bindActionCreators({loadAddStorageModal: loadAddStorageModal, createNewStorage: createNewStorage}, dispatch);
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(App);
```

StorageActions

```
export function fetchStorage() {
  return function(dispatch) {
      var payload = [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: "Fridge2"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: "Closet2"
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            name: "Car2"
        }
    ];
     dispatch({type: "Fetch_Storage", payload: payload});
  }
}

export function loadAddStorageModal(load) {
    return function(dispatch) {
         dispatch({type: "Load_Add_Storage_Modal", payload: load});
    }
}

export function createNewStorage(storage) {
    return function(dispatch) {
         dispatch({type: "New_Storage_Created", payload: storage});
    }
}
```

Reducer

```
export default function reducer(state = {
    fetchedStorages: [],
    openAddStorageModal: false
}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "Fetch_Storage": {
            return {
                fetchedStorages: action.payload
            }
        }
        case "Load_Add_Storage_Modal": {
            return {  
                openAddStorageModal: action.payload,
                fetchedStorages: state.fetchedStorages
            }
        }
        case "New_Storage_Created": {
            return {
                openAddStorageModal: false,
            }
        }
    }


    return state;
}
```

AddStorageModal

```
import React from 'react';

import 'materialize-css/sass/materialize.scss';
import 'materialize-css/js/materialize.js';
import 'font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss';
import '../styles/main.scss';

export default class AddStorageModal extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {storageName: ""}
    }
    handleChange(event) {
       this.setState({storageName: event.target.value});
    }
    render() {
        if (this.props.storages.openAddStorageModal) {
            $('#add-new-storage-modal').openModal({ dismissible: false });
        }
        return (
            <div id="add-new-storage-modal" className="modal" >
                <div className="modal-content">
                    <h6>Enter your new Storage (Freezer, Pantry, etc.) </h6>
                    <div className="row">
                        <form>
                            <div className="input-field col s12 m12 l12 ">
                                <input id="storage_name" type="text" className="validate" value={this.state.storageName}  onChange={this.handleChange} />
                                <label htmlFor="storage_name">Storage Name</label>
                            </div>
                            <br />
                            <h4 className="center">OR</h4>
                            <h6>Enter in the sharing key you were given.</h6>
                            <div className="input-field col s12 m12 l12 ">
                                <input id="sharing_key" type="text" className="validate" />
                                <label htmlFor="sharing_key">Sharking Key</label>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="modal-footer">
                    <a href="#!" className="waves-effect waves-green btn-flat left">Add</a>
                    <a href="#!" className="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat" onClick={() => this.props.loadAddStorageModal(false) }>Cancel</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I get

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined
```

So I am not sure if this just means I am doing redux wrong or if I just made some general error.

Comment: you just forgot to bind handleChange, add `this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)` to the constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass a generic function reference, you need to keep the reference to `this`. You have 2 options:

1. bind `this` to the function, like @nuway said in his answer.
2. Use an arrow function, which also keeps the `this` reference: `onChange={ (event) => this.handleChange(event) }`

Comment: Yea. I just saw that. On a side note as I am setting setState is there away to just make one handleChange event for all my setting of state? I don't want to write a function for each input.

Comment: I also tried this "arrow function" but I get "Cannot read property 'target' of undefined"

Comment: @chobo2 yes you can make one function. if you need to know which element it's coming from, you can check the event argument. it should have the target in it.

Comment: @nuway - Yep was able to do that with target.name. I was unable to get the arrow function working not sure why though.

Comment: @chobo2 Check my edit, I've added the `event` parameter. At first I just wrote generically, but when you're using handlers you should pass the events, it will work for you now.

Answer (score 0):

you need to bind to `this` for the handleChange handler, otherwise `this` inside *handleChange* funtion won't be the react component but rather the input element itself.

```
onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
```